# Auto review comments can save you time

Tags: discussion, comments, review-queues

There is an extension available for Google Chrome called [**AutoReviewComments**](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se), which can save you time if you frequent the review queues, or guide new users with your comments, and I've been using it for quite a while.

Install it → Read instructions → Use it.

Ask me questions, when you have them.

<sub>Note: This is not a paid promotion. This extension is used by thousands of SE users.</sub>

Comment: Ooh, that's handy. This means I can either write ELL or English Language for Learners complete with its link and some blurb without having to search for and C&P the link each and every time. Ooh, nice!

Comment: @Mari-LouA Exactly. Plus, I've been curating comments from moderators to make my own list of canned comments.

Comment: @NVZ Have you seen Meta's [repository of polite responses](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6798/55623)?

Comment: @DanBron yeah. I'd already incorporated parts of it in my list of canned responses

Comment: It's important to note that it is also available as user script on that site. For everyone who doesn't want to use extensions who read their web sites. If run it in tampermonkey for example you have more control over it, making sure it's not reading your banking website ;)

Comment: @Helmar Yeah. Can you edit my question to add that info? I'd like that very much.

Comment: @NVZ I'm currently on mobile, so I will not use that edit button now. ;) You're welcome to add it though.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not trust Google Chrome (maybe I am just old-fashioned). Is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: @Cascabel visit the link in question. Chrome is just one of the possible ways