# Google is a Lexicon, How Do You Like Those Apples?

Tags: discussion, support, status-declined

I'm writing today to debunk the libelous myth you stipulated without citing a single source.

I heard back from the OED, Please see link below. Upon noticing drastic differences between Google Dictionary's content and that of the Living Oxford Dictionary, one can only assume that Google has updated their source to something more credible, and has furthermore received authority by the OED to provide for creative license with regards to content.

They make no claim, and cite no source because they are an oracle and they are not required to divulge their source, which is comprised of many of the worlds most intelligent people who work in the field of applied mathematics.

So yes, again: How do you like those apples?

https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/licensing/google

Please re-open the following question: [Is Google a lexicon?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11056/is-google-a-lexicon/11058?noredirect=1#comment46472_11058)

Sincerely,

Jesse G. Ivy

P.S. Looking at you @Clare https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/users/210913/clare

Also: @MetaEd, please never cite wikipedia. Ever. And be more polite to community members.

Comment: Your previous question wasn’t closed for any reason related to google or OED or lexicons or anything else. It was closer because no one (except you maybe?) understood what the point was in your posting it. If you want it re-opened, edit it to clarify *what outcome you’re looking for from the community* from it. Also the irony of your abjuration to MetaEd to “never cite wikipedia” when you’re here defending your decision to “cite google” is not lost on us. Wikipedia articles recapitulate what’s stated in its cited sources; same thing for google & ODO: if you can’t cite one, you can’t the other.

Comment: The Oxford English Dictionary (OED) is not the dictionary used in Google search results; it is not the same thing as oxforddictionaries.com. You can see that the OED entry for [say](http://www.oed.com/viewdictionaryentry/Entry/171590) is not even close to the [definition given by Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+say). (Note that the full OED requires a subscription.)

Comment: @Dan, the question was simple "Is Google a Lexicon?", and the answer is true, which I subsequently found out through my own research by contacting OED UK directly. Who confirmed my suspicion.

Simply looking for agreement. I do not appreciate any of this venom.

Comment: https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/licensing/google

Comment: Venom begets venom! Though, to be more fair, the “precious” in my first comment was intended to be “previous” [now corrected], so somewhat less venomous. And that Google uses some information from ODO doesn’t make Google a lexicon anymore than that Google uses some information from WebMD makes Google a doctor or that is provides recipes upon asking makes Google a recipe book and so on. That said, if you want to make progress, I think a clear statement from you that you understand ODO and OED are *not the same thing* would go a long way.

Comment: @JesseIvy You cannot copypasta without a link. It's the rules. It isn't our rules at ELU either. It's an SE rule.  This you must not use: https://www.google.com/search?ei=lUFZWtjJAbKj_Qa5xKOoAg&q=define+pasta&oq=define+pasta&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l3j0i10k1j0l2j0i10k1j0j0i10k1.5828.6098.0.6260.5.4.0.0.0.0.152.277.0j2.2.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..3.2.274...0i20i264k1.0.zxkbcccWLck

Answer (score 5):

Pasting in the results of Googling a word is unacceptable on ELU for many, many reasons. This has been covered elsewhere, but here are a few of them, in no particular order:

1. It does not meet the [network-wide requirements for referencing other’s work](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).
2. You have to provide a link when pasting in someone else's work.
3. You have to cite where the information comes from, and Googling never provides an actual citation of where the original information change from time.
4. Not everyone gets the same Googling results as you get.
5. Googling results can and do change from time without notice or tracking history.
6. LMGTFY is justly banned throughout the Stack Exchange network, so working around that ban is forbidden.
7. We are not a link farm: answers should be mostly your own words.
8. [Questions that can be answered by mere Googling should be closed](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2160/2085).

Comment: Wow. An answer from tchrist. Your statements are incorrect. Please use google and search for "google definition", the results at the top, before the links, under "DICTIONARY", are from Google Dictionary. Google Dictionary is a very real source. It is derived from the OED.

Comment: I say again: Google and Oxford are Partners. It is a new day. Please review the link. https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/licensing/google

Comment: I like item #7 quite a bit though. "We are not a link farm: answers should be mostly your own words", Couldn't agree more. Nor is this site about squabbling. I am looking for acknowledgement that Google Dictionary is a citable source. And today I am staking my reputation on it. I have a bad reoutation. It is sometimes awesome to realize that while you cannot believe everything you see on the internet, the dictionaries are a lock.

Comment: @JesseIvy You are mistaken. Googling is not derived from the OED: I know the OED, and Senator, you’re no Jack Kennedy.  And there is no reference provided. You are out of alignment with network policy and site policy. You may not use Googling copypasta as though it were a citable reference: it is not, and you are not going to convince us to change that policy by yelling at us and telling us we are wrong.

Comment: Nice! I provided the reference sent from OED UK above. Again. As a professional corporation, and partner of Oxford, Google is not required to cite a source. They are the source. In partnership with Oxford. I'm not yelling. You are being impolite, and refusing to acknowledge the source.

To your point, it is true that Google Dictionary is not the OED. Google serves their own content. Which has been reviewed, and approved by OED editors. And that is in large part my point. It's content is largely derived from the original definitive source (OED) in partnership. Read the link.

Comment: Your suggestion that Google Dictionary cannot be cited is ridiculous. If you are truly saying that then the free living dictionary at oxforddictionaries.com cannot be cited, nor can Webster's Dictionary, or any other lexicon. And that is a bizarre claim. It is just as credible, if not more so.

Comment: https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/licensing/google

Comment: Sounds as if you're friends with Jack Kennedy, and that you know me? Both are inaccurate claims I have no doubt. I've been to Boston. Wintered there in 1999. You don't know me. Look it up.

Answer (score 2):

I'm marking this [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) because it is not possible for us to re-open a failed migration stub that bounced back.

The solution is simple: if you wish to cite the OED, then by all means please do so. But Googling is not the OED. QED.

Comment: Thank you for your time. :)