# How do I write a long response to an answerer?

Tags: discussion

Please note that I'm asking about a thread on this meta ([Forum tone, reasonableness, and the possibility of a curated stack](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7213/forum-tone-reasonableness-and-the-possibility-of-a-curated-stack)), not for general use within ELU. I will be needing more than 600 characters for sure. Do I answer my own question and put it there?

Comment: Post an answer might be best, or edit your question and include your reflections. Although I think it's already overlong to begin with, but that's MO.

Comment: I would recommend that a **substantial** edit to a question after an answer has been received is generally Not A Good Thing To Do.

Answer (score 6):

You don't respond, especially if the response is that long. **Stack Exchange is not a discussion forum.**

More in the way of discussion is inherent in Meta, but a post which is longer than 600 characters should really be crafted into its own entity. A response that long to an answer implies a contrary view; a response that long to a question implies it's really an answer.

Answer your own question with the answer you think it should have, and let the community vote on the alternatives thus presented.

Comment: Thank you for the response. To be clear, this applies equally to meta? There is a discussion tag built into the software. I think there is some confusion as to this point among experienced users, as it is quickly becoming a heated topic in the question I linked to above.

Comment: @Albatrosspro Clarified in the answer.

Comment: @Albatrosspro: I'm coming late to this .. um ..  discussion. I noticed that you answered your question and then deleted it, thereby making it visible only to people with high points. Was that the intent? In any event, I haven't gone through all the discussion (tl;dr) yet, so I'm not really sure whether I have anything to say on whatever the topic turns out to be. Surely there are problems with the SE model here; but there are problems with the group, and with the clientele, as well. To say nothing of problems with English grammar and usage.

Comment: @John Lawler I had no idea that deleted answers are still visible to some users! Oops. I simply wanted to get rid of it.