# What is the difference between these 2 questions?

Tags: discussion

I hope this is not a duplicate. I will delete it if found so.

Many of new posters might not know what would be the appropriate/right questions for EL&U and they might not even know how to take the tour. Some questions should have been posted in ELL but I don't think many of them are aware that ELL exists.

Today, there were 2 questions which were usual suspects for the right word. The first one was "put on hold" and the second one was not.

I don't understand why the second one is not "put on hold" when the first one is.

One commented, "Take the words you'd use in your mother tongue, then use a ***bilingual dictionary of your liking to look up their English counterparts***."

How many questions in the past do you think should be "put on hold" **if you use the *same standard and argument***?

The OP of the second question will be able to find the answer in a dictionary or any site as easily as the OP of the first question would. Furthermore, the first question has ***an upvote*** while the second has none. (I wanted to downvote it, but decided not to to post this question.)

I understand it could be very subjective decision to pick the worse of the two, but I believe the same standard sould be applied. ***At least a question with an upvote should not be put on hold*** as it indicates some are showing an interest in the question or like it. (I am not the one who upvoted it)

Or questions like the first one ***should be migrated to ELL***. I think it is more appropriate than putting it [on hold] and ***fairer to the OP.***

I read this long [question and discussion](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4491/this-is-not-a-site-for-serious-english-language-enthusiasts-and-it-never-will) and I can understand the difficulties this site is facing.

[Question No.1](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/281300/how-to-describe-someone-who-speaks-less-and-shows-in-action)

How to describe someone who speaks less and shows in action? [on hold]

> Suppose someone often speaks less however he is intelligent and
>   skillfull. Basically, he shows in action rather in speaking (in a
>   positive way). I wonder what kinds of words can be used to describe
>   such a person.

[Question No. 2](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/281252/what-do-you-call-a-topic-thats-ignored-by-people-because-its-boring-abstract)

What do you call a topic that's ignored by people because it's boring, abstract, or improper?

> Example topics: Existentialism, quantum mechanics, abstract math,
>   suicide, genocide, etc.
>
> Example sentence:
>
> He started shaping his fears and [...] topics into stories.
>   Maybe
>   shunned?

Comment: Personally, I find the endless stream of questions about "words to describe this type of person" tedious in general.

Comment: Also. question 1 seems more opinion-based because it asks for multiple words and gives no example sentence.

Comment: @sumelic I agree with you again. Giving non-related topics as an example is equally opinion-based, too as talking aout quantum mechnics and suicide/genocide could be different (which is also opinion-based). My point is if we had migrated the first question to ELL, we might have guided the OP better than just putting it on hold.

Comment: So are you actually interested in hearing about the differences people see between these questions, or is it a rhetorical question?

Comment: In general, I disagree that " At least a question with an upvote should not be put on hold." People upvote for both good and bad reasons. I also disagree that "migrating to ELL [...] is more appropriate than putting it [on hold] and fairer to the OP." ELL also has "primarily opinion-based" as a close reason; so migrating is not always better than closing. In this specific case, the question might be received well on ELL; the OP can just delete the question on ELU and re-post on ELL. That's generally easier than migrating anyway; the only reason to migrate is if there are already good answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single word requests have some additional specific requirements because the site gets so many of them and a lot of them are terrible.  See the [tag info](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) for details.  Neither is a great question (as evidenced by the lack of upvotes on both), but Question #2 certainly comes closer to meeting the requirements and is a better question overall.  #1 is barely comprehensible and shows no evidence of research.

I probably wouldn't have chosen "opinion based" for the first question, but who knows how that happened.  It looks like it was ultimately closed as "off-topic / lacking research", which seems right to me.

Migrating questions directly to ELL is suitable in some cases, but not when it's flat-out a bad question.  It would get placed on hold just as quickly over there.

Up votes and close votes are deliberately distinct concepts in StackExchange.   As Sumelic said in a comment, "people upvote for both good and bad reasons".  Plus, something can be very popular and yet still be a duplicate or inappropriate for the site.

Comment: I upvoted your answer and thanks. If some people know or think "people upvote for both good and bad reasons", what good is it doing here?

Comment: @Rathony - Just because a system is imperfect doesn't mean it provides no value.  It just means you maybe don't want to rely too much on what is essentially a subjective "like" system.

Comment: What I meant was there is a room for improvement. That's all.